# Python 3.[12] urllib

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x, urllib

i am working on a little script grabbing some files from a website. First i create a list of potential urls within the website. This worked fine with Python 3.1 but not with Python 3.2. I guess it is a question on encoding but i am not sure how to realise it in an elegant way. Can you help me?

```
def get_urls(username, password, userid):
    cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'login' : username, 'password' : password})
    opener.open(BASE_URL+"/bg/login", login_data)
    url = BASE_URL + "/bg/user/" + userid + "?finished=1"
    resp = opener.open(url)
    result = resp.read()
    txt = result.decode("iso-8859-1")
    liste = (re.findall("/bg/export/[\d]{4,8}",txt))
    return liste
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work with Python 3.2? What is the expected output vs. received output for a given page? Where does it go wrong, if you add `print` statements every line or so to see what's going on?

Comment: The error message: TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be str. So i have to encode everything to byte code but what is the most elegant way to do so?

Comment: What line is the error on? Edit the __full traceback__ into your question. Also, don't sign your question -- delete that.

Comment: The error is on line"opener.open(BASE_URL+"/bg/login", login_data)". What do you mean with "Edit the full traceback"?

Comment: Edit your question and add this stuff properly formatted, don't add it in comments. By the full traceback I mean everything that prints out when the error occurs.

Comment: I would suggest that you use the charset value that `resp.headers['content-type']` contains, instead of using the hard-coded `iso-8859-1` to decode `result`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be here:

`login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'login' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open(BASE_URL+"/bg/login", login_data)`

`urllib.parse.urlencode` outputs string not an iterable.

Comment: Yes, problem solved: Encoding the login_data variable by

    login_data = login_data.encode("utf-8") works fine for the moment. Thx!